# OOPython making answer space separated

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have these classes:

```
class Animal(abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def speak(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def speak_twice(self):
        self.speak()
        self.speak()

class Cat(Animal):        
    def speak(self):
        print("Meow")

class Dog(Animal):    
    def speak(self):
        print("Voff")
```

And the outcome is this:

```
Meow
Meow
```

when I use `buster.speak_twice()`

I want the outcome to be this:

```
"Meow Meow"
```

I've tried changing a lot in the `speak_twice` function, like making the 2 different speak to `str()` and returning it and I've tried to change it to print.

Comment: You can't do what you want without changing how the `speak()` methods work. Those functions use `print()` to write directly to the terminal, they don't *return* their value to the caller. You'd have to change those to use `return 'Meow'` and `return 'Voff'` instead, so you can then use those return values and produce a new string.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm.